# How to collect a judgement in Maryland?

Tags: united-states, debt-collection, maryland

I have a $30,000 judgement against an individual in the State of Maryland. The case was adjudicated in Small Claims Court in Maryland. I'd like to collect the judgement but the individual is not responding to my letters informing him of the judgement and demands for payment.

According to sites like [CJS Creative](https://sellmyjudgments.com/blog/) it may be as easy as garnishing his wages. Garnishment is appealing because it does not depend on a debtor. I may also have other opportunities, like putting a lien on his house or car.

His ex-wife despises him so I have a steady stream of current information about him, like where he is living, his employer, his vehicles, etc.

I'm an individual and not a corporation. I don't need the money now; but I would like to collect it sometime, like in 2 years or 5 years or 10 years.

How does one collect a judgement from an individual in the State of Maryland?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://mdcourts.gov/sites/default/files/import/district/forms/civil/dccv060br.pdf

Comment: Thanks @dwizum. No that did not make my search results. Sigh... A quick question... Given that I have the information in Step 1, can I skip that step? Or do I still need to perform them?

Comment: I have no idea. I am not really in a position of expertise to answer your question, I just thought it was interesting so I googled it, saw that pdf, and figured you may want it as part of your research.